# Compare file between commits when folder structure has changed

Tags: git, git-diff

**Question:**
How do I `git diff` a particular file when the folder structure has changed between `commit_hash_1` and `commit_hash_2`?

**What I know:**
I can `git diff` a file between two commits with:

```
git diff commit_hash_1 commit_hash_2 folder/file.ext
```

**Attempted Solutions:**
**1.** My guess was something like:

```
git diff commit_hash_1:/folder/file.ext commit_hash_2:/new_folder/file.ext
```

But that doesn't work; it gives me:

```
fatal: Path '/new_folder/file.ext' does not exist in 'commit_hash_2'
```

**2.** So the other option is:

```
git diff commit_hash_1 commit_hash_2 new_folder/file.ext
```

But that starts a comparison between the `commit_hash_2` `file.ext` and `/dev/null`.

Comment: 1. Seems like the right approach. Error message suggests your syntax is right but path is wrong. Did you double check the path? Also try the same syntax but compare unmoved files to make sure your base assumptions are correct.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the slashes in my first attempted solution - can't believe I didn't try removing those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attempted solution is nearly correct, but those opening slashes are wrong. Try:

```
git diff commit_hash_1:folder/file.ext commit_hash_2:new_folder/file.ext
```

Thanks @dlsso for sending me on the right track.